# C++ crash when using OpenCV's Canny function in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, 64-bit, windows-server-2012-r2

```
while (true)
{
    cap.read(frame);

    if (frame.empty())
    {
        cap.release();
        break;
    }

    cv::cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::GaussianBlur(frame, frame, cv::Size(3, 3), 1.8);

    cv::Mat edgeImage;
    cv::Canny(frame, edgeImage, 120, 255, 5);

    imshow("window", edgeImage);
    cv::waitKey(15);
}
```

Visual Studio 2015 with Update3.
Build it x64 with OpenCV 3.4.3(x64).

This is very strange error.

When run this app in Windows7, It's OK. But in Windows Server 2012 R2, Not working.
App crash and dead.

After app crash, I found log in Event Viewer in Control Panel.

> Can't access file 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140.dll'

But the file is in there, and also I installed all of VC++ runtime redistribution package (2005,2008,2010,2012,2013,2015) x86 and x64 both.

**More, Here is best stange things.**
When I comment cv::Canny and app works just fine!
(of course I change below imshow line to imshow("window", frame);)

I don't know what happended to this application...
Please give me any advice.

*I can't debug it with VS2015 in Server 2012 R2 due to some reasons*

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

The server CPU is Intel Xeon Gold 6126.

I think OpenCV 3.4.3 has a bug about it.

OpenCV 3.4.5 works great.