# cv::split() crashes on Xeon processor but works elsewhere

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, crash

I am using pre-built opencv lib & dll, version 3.4.3 Winpack (downloaded from official site https://opencv.org/releases.html).

Till now everything worked fine, but recently my code started to crash. 
It is one specific function that causes this crash: **cv::split()**. It is a common utility funtion to extract channels 
from cv::Mat array. The crash occurs only on Xeon processor, Windows Server 2012. Regardless of preceding calls or context, it just crashes immediately on this call and the application just closes.
On other processors the same .exe works without problems, the code is normally tested on Windows 10 with ordinary processors. I don't have Xeon processor at hand to test every function, but the mentioned crash could be reproduced 100% on a **Xeon Gold** machine and I have used quite a lot of different library functions and they worked there, so it is the first one that crashed.

It seems that some functions' runtime simply contains instruction that are incompatible with the Xeon processor so it just crashes there.

Question: how do I know in advance whether certain openCV function will work or not on a Xeon processor?

Currently I have just removed cv::split() calls from my code and replced it by cv::extractChannel() methods which works fine on all tested platforms. I suspect one option would be to compile a custom version of the lib and disable specific instructions, but that will need knowledge of what to disable, etc, so frankly I am not in the mood involving 
custom compiled version for what seems relatively 'standard architecture' (Xeon processor).

What can you suggest to avoid these errors?

Maybe there is  a list of openCV functions that are known to be 'special' (not for Xeon processor so I can just avoid them)?

Code example:

```
# include  <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
int main ( int  argc,  char*  argv[] ) 
{
cv::Mat Patch = cv::imread ( "image.png", -1 );
cv::Mat Patch_planes[4];
cv::split ( Patch, Patch_planes );
return 0;
}
```

Compiler command (Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.15.26732.1 for x64):

```
cl.exe "minim.cpp" /EHsc /W2 /I "c:\VCLIB\openCV-3.4.3" "c:\VCLIB\openCV-3.4.3\lib\opencv_world343.lib" /link /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE
```

Comment: Provide [mcve] to reproduce this. | Define "Xeon" -- Intel has been making chips with that name for some 20 years now, you've got to be more specific. | Does it happen with debug build? Can you get the backtrace and other details about the exact error? Does it happen with other versions? Did you report the problem on the OpenCV issue tracker with all the details?

Comment: @DanMašek added code example. It was Xeon Gold processor in my case. I don't own the machine and don't have permanent access but it can be reproduced with a common system crash, the app just closes without much further info.

Comment: Xeon Gold.. so Skylake a 5xxx or 6xxx... know the exact model number? Those are quite recent, so barring bugs an 8 month old release should work with them. Really, other than testing on all the platforms you're willing to support, it's gonna be extremely difficult to guarantee everything works... although the cases when it doesn't will likely be weird corner cases that are hard to debug.. You really need more details about the nature and location of the error. Like I said, check that it's not specific to this specific release. Try debug build to get the stack trace. "Crash" is not enough info.

Comment: Chances are much higher that one of the OpenCV files got corrupted on disk on that system. In your situation, if possible, I'd do a complete reinstall of OpenCV as a next step.

Comment: I had same problem in Xeon Gold when using 3.4.3
You should upgrade OpenCV to 3.4.5 later
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54071839/c-crash-when-using-opencvs-canny-function-in-windows-server-2012-r2

Answer (score 0):

> How do I know in advance whether certain openCV function will work or not on a Xeon processor?

You don't.  The compiler will use whatever instructions it deems most suitable to compile any particular piece of code, subject to the constraints given on the command line.

So to be safe (assuming it is an 'illegal instruction' error), you probably do need to compile openCV for the least capable processor you need to support and then check the performance hit on other processors.  Either that or check the CPU in your installer and install a version of openCV tailored to that processor.  Yuk, I don't envy you.